# Do, custom fonts work in UITextView that was loaded in cocos2d layer?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextview, cocos2d-iphone

Do, custom fonts work in UITextView ?

I loaded UITextView *textView in cocos2d layer. And I trying to set the font of the text as 
Copperplate Gothic Bold. I downloaded the font file Coprgtb.TTF. But, the text is not adjusting to this font. The system fonts are working, but the custom fonts are not working ?
I added the font file in resources folder.
what can I do to make them work ?
Thank You .

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you found a solution in the past near-year, but here's an answer anyway:

I don't believe there is any reason why custom UITextView fonts shouldn't work in a cocos2d layer, but please do try referencing the font by the filename (exactly as in your resources) rather than the font name. I know that's different to the way system fonts work, but it has worked for me with custom fonts in cocos2d.